# PHP:mkdir() can't create folder

Tags: php, mkdir

I know there are similar topics,but when I tried using them, I still got the same error.
The problem is this:

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home/... on line 30
```

I got this code:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755);
```

What's the problem?I already have memberFiles folder.

Comment: If you echo `$id` do you get anything? Also, are you in the `memberFiles` directory when you're creating these folders?

Comment: @Kacey Yes,I got the id that I needed to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete path to your file. You can use it with `__DIR__` then you have the actual directory form your file.

```
mkdir(__DIR__."/memberFiles/$id", 0755);
```

for example. And you should check if the directory is available before you try create it.

```
if(!is_dir(__DIR__."/memberFiles/$id")) {
    mkdir(__DIR__."/memberFiles/$id", 0755);
}
```

If you have PHP < 5.3 then its `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__`.

Comment: Just a quick caveat – if you're < PHP 5.3 you won't have `__DIR__` but will instead need to use `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Thanks i have added this to my answer.